# Boostrap Thumbnail with Anchors doesn't click on mobile device

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a clickable thumbnail using bootstrap css
It works great on my desktop but doesn't click on my mobile device.
What is wrong ?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-sx-12">
<a href="/local/newpage.php">
        <div class="thumbnail">
           <img src="images/myimage.jpg" class="img-rounded"></img>
            <p class="caption"><strong>caption text</strong></p>
     </div>
</a>
</div
```

This code works perfectly on my desktop, doesn't work on my phone.

Comment: can you show your CSS for thumbnail and caption, or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: this is the actual site, www.hamoshavaclub.co.il (I will remove this later)...

Comment: CSS is bootstarp defaults. no special customization.

Comment: Ah, the clue is in the actual site. If you switch to a mobile view and 'inspect element' on a thumbnail you'll see that the sidebar element appears to be rendering over the top of the thumbnail

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although I'm not sure how to fix this. it's a bootstrap grid - shouldn't the grid enforce separation ?

Comment: @ChaoticNadirs - Thanks, Found the error - col-sx instead of col-xs